# ¿Cómo agrupar tuplas repetidas en una lista de tuplas en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy comenzando a programar en Python y me surgió el siguiente problema y no sé como resolverlo.

Tengo esta lista de tuplas:

```
cf =[(0.25, 15150),
     (0.5, 500.0),
     (0.5, 900.0),
     (1.0, 500.0),
     (1.0, 900.0),
     (1.5, 500.0),
     (1.5, 900.0),
     (2.0, 500.0),
     (2.0, 30900.0),
     (2.5, 500.0),
     (3.0, 10500.0)]
```

Necesito que aquellas tuplas cuyo primer valor este repetido se unifiquen y el segundo valor se sume. El output debería ser el siguiente:

```
cf =[(0.25, 15150),
     (0.5, 1400.0),
     (1.0, 1400.0),
     (1.5, 1400.0),
     (2.0, 31400.0),
     (2.5, 500.0),
     (3.0, 10500.0)]
```

Si alguno me puede ayudar con esto se los agradezco!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra forma bastante simple es usar la función [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) y un poco de comprensión de listas:

```
from itertools import groupby

l = [(k, sum([e[1] for e in g])) for k, g in groupby(cf, lambda x:x[0])]

print(l)

[(0.25, 15150), 
 (0.5, 1400.0), 
 (1.0, 1400.0), 
 (1.5, 1400.0), 
 (2.0, 31400.0), 
 (2.5, 500.0), 
 (3.0, 10500.0)]
```

Con `groupby(cf, lambda x:x[0])` agrupamos la lista `cf` por el primer valor de cada tupla, es decir `lambda x:x[0]`, luego simplemente iteramos por cada grupo y dentro de este por cada uno de los valores del segundo elemento de cada tupla para terminar aplicando un `sum()`

Comment: Dentro de `sum` se puede dejar como expresión generadora y así evitar crear la lista: `sum(e[1] for e in g)`. Por otro lado, esta solución solo es correcta si la lista de tuplas está ordenada previamente. Tendrías que hacer un `sorted(cf)` dentro del  `groupby`.

Answer (score 2):

Ya te han dado una solución *programática* mediante sets. Lo bonito de python es que cuenta con una gran librería estándar que se puede aprovechar para resolver estos problemas.

De modo similar a usar sets se podría haber usado diccionarios. A partir de la lista de tuplas es muy sencillo construir uno:

```
res = dict(lista)
```

El problema es que en este diccionario sólo aparece el valor de una de las tuplas que estén duplicadas y nosotros queremos se sumen sus valores.

El truco sería definir el diccionario con el [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), permitiendo hacer lo que pides con pocas líneas de código:

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(int)
for (k,v) in lista:
    res[k] += v

print(sorted(res.items()))
```

El primer argumento de `defaultdict` es lo que se conoce como *función factoría* que se usa para crear el valor por defecto de los items del diccionario. Al pasar aquí el constructor `int` indicamos que los items del diccionario son por defecto números enteros, los cuáles tienen valor `0` por defecto (o sea, `int() == 0`). De este modo, es sencillo agrupar items sumando sus valores.

Comment: Anda... había leido mal la pregunta y no vi que había que sumar los elementos repetidos. En ese caso mi solución con conjuntos se volvería farragosa y usar diccionarios es mucho más directo. Borro mi respuesta.